# Using data from fitnesse table as a variable

Tags: testing, fitnesse

I'm just getting started with Fitnesse.
I am trying to use a result of a query (number?) and with that result use it in another test fixture. so e.g.

```
!|Create Account                                                                                    |
|Contractor No  |Account State  |Account Name  |Account Type  |Invoice Template Name|Number?|Result?|
|${ContractorNo}|${AccountState}|${AccountName}|${AccountType}|${InvoiceTempName}   |       |TRUE   |

!|Check Account                      |
|AccountNo           |Account Exists?|
|(result from number?)|TRUE          |
```

is there anyway of doing this? ive tried this: [SymbolTestTables](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SymbolsInTestTables), but this seems to be for one entire record instead of just the result from one function.

As i said im new to fitnesse so i apologize if this is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the page you are referring to is the Fit style symbols.

I recommend that folks either use Slim, or move to FitLibrary; as both are better supported than just FIT.

If you are doing things the Slim way, you would want to look at this page: [Symbols in tables](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables)

And if you were doing the Slim way, your table would look like this:

```
!|Create Account                                                                                    |
|Contractor No  |Account State  |Account Name  |Account Type  |Invoice Template Name|Number?               |Result?|
|${ContractorNo}|${AccountState}|${AccountName}|${AccountType}|${InvoiceTempName}   |$accountNumber=      |TRUE   |

!|Check Account                |
|AccountNo     |Account Exists?|
|$accountNumber|TRUE           |
```

I'm not as familiar with the FitLibrary style, so I will refer you to their documentation: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fitlibrary/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

With .NET/Fit, you can use << and >> to store and recall values, but I don't know if this is supported with Java:

```
!|Create Account                                                                                    |
|Contractor No  |Account State  |Account Name  |Account Type  |Invoice Template Name|Number?        |Result?|
|${ContractorNo}|${AccountState}|${AccountName}|${AccountType}|${InvoiceTempName}   |>>AccountNumber|TRUE   |

!|Check Account                      |
|AccountNo           |Account Exists?|
|<<AccountNumber     |TRUE          |
```

Comment: Well, it isn't supported in java when using SliM.  FitLibrary has it's own tweaks to these things.