# How to use a runtime variable in FitNesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Let's say I have the following FitNesse page:

```
!| com.myproject.fitnesse.fixtures.SSHFixture |
| set host | ${hostSi1} |
| set port | ${port} |
| set user | ${user}  |
| connect |
| show | run command | pwd |
| disconnect |
www.<variable>.com
```

The page contains one table and a link. The table will execute the console command `pwd`. How do I save the result of that command in a FitNesse Variable? I want then to use the variable within the same page. For example in the mentioned link.

Some resources are mentioning SLIM style, but I have no idea how to accomplish that in my case:
[Using data from fitnesse table as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450909/using-data-from-fitnesse-table-as-a-variable)

Comment: You can switch the test system to 'slim' by adding the line `!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}` to the parent page (i.e. suite page) of the page that uses your fixture. But this will probably also impact your fixture and test table (which looks like a 'script table'). Can you share your fixture code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fried Hoeben: Yes its a script. Got a solution from my colleague.

Let's say you have Fixture for DB stuff and there's method called 'execute query' which will return result of the query.

Setting value to variable 'myname' so we could use in another fixture table as '@{myname}'.

```
!| com.mystest.fitnesse.fixtures.DBFixture |
| set database | ${dbName} |
| set username | ${dbUser} |
| set password | ${dbPassword} |
| connect | ${dbType} | to | ${dbUrl} | database | ${dbPort} |
| set | myname | execute query | SELECT name FROM customer WHERE id = 1 |
| disconnect |
```

Use of variable 'myname':

```
!| com.mytest.fitnesse.fixtures.SSHFixture |
| set host | ${host}                   |
| set port | ${port}                   | 
| set user | ${user}                   |
| connect                              |
| show     | execute|echo @{myname} |  
| disconnect                           |
```

Not sure if the feature of set is part of fitnesse default impl. or of our company implementation.